# Convert char back to mtype in Promela Spin

Tags: spin, promela

Let's say, for instance, I have the following

```
mtype = {ONE, TWO, THREE} ;
mtype array[3] ;
mtype test ;
test = array[0] ;
printf("Test is %e\n", test) ;
```

I get

```
Test is 1
```

which I understand is because the underlying variable is a char type.  However, I would like to get the mtype of that char, is there any way to cross reference a char back to its mtype?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `array[3]` with valid values.  Here is what I get:

```
== foo.pml ==
mtype = {ONE, TWO, THREE};
mtype array[3];
mtype test;

init {
  array[0] = TWO;   // initialize!
  test = array[0];
  printf ("Test is '%e'\n", test);
}

$ spin foo.pml 
      Test is 'TWO'
1 process created
```

If I then modify `foo.pml` to remove the initialization of `array[0]` then the output is:

```
$ spin foo.pml 
      Test is '0'
1 process created
```